# How can I analyse the Performance Report in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, ruby-jmeter

PerfMon and Monitor in Jmeter is working fine.
I know how to extract report and all.
Can anyone explain me.
How to check the performance report?
How can i judge the Server?
What all Problems getting on Server?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice report analyzer tool at "https://sense.blazemeter.com".

You have to upload your .jtl log files to use it.